# getting SW version by bash script for uninstall preinstalled software/notifying easily by assigning variable to it. Please share more ideas

Tags: linux, bash, variables, version, autodeploy

Please share more ideas to get software version from bash command and use it as variable later.

```
 su --version
su (GNU coreutils) 5.97
Copyright etc.
```

and create variable of the result of it.
Something like I tried below.

```
su --version >/tmp/temp.txt

if [ -f /tmp/temp.txt ]; then
    elv=`cat /tmp/temp.txt | gawk 'BEGIN {FS="(GNU coreutils)"} {print $2}' | gawk 'BEGIN {FS="."} {print $1}'`
    #Version String. Just a shortcut to be used later
    els=el$elv
else
    echo "Unable to determine version. I can't continue"
    exit 1
fi
```

---

```
if [ `rpm -qa | egrep -c -i "^mysql-"` -gt 0 ]; then
cat << EOF

It appears that the distro-supplied version of MySQL is at least partially installed,
or a prior installation attempt failed.

Please remove these packages, as well as their dependencies (often postfix), and then
retry this script:

$(rpm -qa | egrep -i "^mysql-")

EOF
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If your script is being deployed in an environment where you don't already know the versions of software available, it's better to stick to the POSIX standard rather than try to detect what is available.

Comment: Thanks chepher I am planning to create auto deployment  script for  my web-application which is depends on MySQL and planning to deploy scenario,,,, so if some one who is planning to deploy it,have any pre installed mysql then this script will notify them or later uninstall it and install the required mysql itself.!

Comment: Version dependencies are something that should be resolved *before* run-time. Just document that the script should not be run if MySQL x.y.z is not already installed.

Comment: I have updated my question details, here, thanks for your comment, but I am planning to do auto uninstalling the previous version as well, if you have any idea or relevant criteria then pls comment

Comment: I would just package your script with `rpm`, and make the correct version of MySQL a package dependency. Let your script assume that the right version of `mysql` is available.

Comment: I would do it,if  fails to find out the right approach...but let see what our **developer community** comes with different ideas!

Comment: There is no general solution to getting the version number of a command-line utility. It varies from utility to utility; there are no applicable standards. If you are specifically interested in extracting the version number of the `mysql` client, you should probably ask a more specific question.

Comment: Hi **@rici** , thanks for your comment, I got my answer now,Specifically my script is using Jre8u45 and applicable to DB2 / mysql with specific version and so my question is apparently right but till yet no one had general solution. Thanks I am Happy with traditional method to release per-requisites list with my script to solve dependencies. :)  I have created script to identify version but still not correct and so I like to work on it in meantime. !

Comment: so you're looking to capture version # for DB2/msql and JRE ? At least for JRE there are multiple vendor format's you'd have to deal with. I don't see a generic solution for these 3 (just for example). You could construct special code to grab version #s for each program. But you can't be guaranteed that a vendor won't decide to change their version info output. So how important is this to you? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks  @shellter can you post here reference for jre version capturing script document. For DB2/mysql I will update autodeploy script with usecases.  thanks a mil.   btw I am going to put it in my ftp server and website so anyone can **wget** it and download latest script.

Comment: I don't have access to either DB2 or mysql at my work. You can consult the  documentation for both and find out how to generate the version information. Update your question with those commands AND their output and I'll see what I can do. Good luck.

Comment: Also, per  your example above, learn to use the power of pipes and awk more directly. Maybe `elv=$(su -- version 2>&1 | awk '/GNU coreutils/{verNum=$NF; sub(/\.*$/, "", verNum);print  verNum; #dbg print  "verNum="verNum; exit}')` (untested, but close). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks **@shellter** I will update after working on it in this weekend